# Super class constructor getting sub class name as a string

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, constructor

Here's one. I have a base class for all my exceptions. The base class retrieves a message from app.config which is based on the class name. So if I have 10 exceptions I have 10 messages in app.config.

```
// EBusinessClassExceptions inherits from ApplicationException
public EBusinessClassExceptions(string msgType, params object[] objects)
  : base(string.Format(exceptionMessagesServices.GetMessage(msgType), objects))
{
}
```

So msgType is the class name of the exception to look for.

A sample sub class is:

```
// sub class
public class EHiddenFromWebException : EBusinessClassExceptions
{
  public EHiddenFromWebException(int sampleID)
    : base("EHiddenFromWebException", sampleID)
  {
  }
}
```

But what I don't like is the way I have to use the class name as a string. So a better version is this:

```
// sub class
public EHiddenFromWebException(int sampleID)
  : base(typeof(EHiddenFromWebException).Name, sampleID)
{
}
```

This way I don't have to list the class name as a string, and the compiler verifies the class name. But if I have 10 exceptions, each one's constructor is the same - it just does this:

```
typeof(thisClass).Name
```

What I want to be able to write is just:

```
// sub class
public EHiddenFromWebException(int sampleID)
  : base(sampleID)
{
}
```

And have the typeof in the parent constructor. But to do this, the parent constructor has to determine the class name of the sub class. And that's where I'm stuck...

If this was an instance method I could probably use this somehow but I'm stuck because it's a constructor.

EDIT - note you can't use "this" from inside :base() which I beleive I need to call the parent constructor

Comment: Curiously Recurring Template Pattern may be your best bet.

Comment: You can use `this.GetType()` within base class constructor to get the derived type, but it will be resolved at runtime, which will give you a little bit of performance overhead.

Comment: I cant use this inside :base() I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that you can't use `this` in `base()`, but you can just override Message property.

```
public class EBusinessClassExceptions : ApplicationException
{
    public override string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetType().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AHa - now that I like...I'll try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you. Gets the name of the derived class from **inside** the constructor of the base class.

```
public class EBusinessClassExceptions
    {
        public EBusinessClassExceptions(int sampleID)
        {
            Type type = GetType();
            string name = type.Name;

            Console.WriteLine("Im gonna get an exception message for {0} with sample {1}", name, sampleID);
        }
    }

    public class EHiddenFromWebException : EBusinessClassExceptions
    {
        public EHiddenFromWebException(int sampleID) : base (sampleID)
        {

        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        EHiddenFromWebException ex = new EHiddenFromWebException(123);       

    }
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for this - but how do I call the parent class constructor? Has to be from within : Base I think where I can't use this?

Comment: Why do you need to call the parent class constructor?

Comment: That's a godo question. The parent class of EBusinessClassException is ApplicationException - so by calling that constructor that actually throws the exception. If I use your idea I'll have to explicitly throw the exception from in there I guess - I'll have a look at that. Thanks

Comment: I don't this this will work - I will have to throw an exception myselft from inside an exception constructor - that will be a recursive call to myself I think...the easiest way is @qxg's suggestion to override the virtual message property - which I did and works fine. Thank anyway.